# Django - Trouble adding User to User Group with custom User Model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Previously, I have been using the default Django user model and have been adding users to specific user groups when they register with no problem using this code in my views.py:

`user.save()
 user.groups.add(Group.objects.get(name='customers'))`

However, I have now changed to a custom user model so I can remove the 'username' field in my register form and now this code no longer works. This error message is being thrown when new users try to register:

'User' object has no attribute 'groups'

I have searched but can't find an answer to this question. I am very new to working on the backend with Django so please be very descriptive in your answers (i.e where I need to put the code you suggest, models.py/views.py/forms.py etc). Any help would be much appreciated!

My models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
)

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, first_name, last_name, password=None, is_staff=False, is_admin=False):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must enter an email")

        if not password:
            raise ValueError("Users must enter a password")

        if not first_name:
            raise ValueError("Users must enter their first name")

        if not last_name:
            raise ValueError("Users must enter their last name")

        user_obj = self.model(
            email = self.normalize_email(email),
            first_name = first_name,
            last_name = last_name,
        )
        user_obj.set_password(password) #set and change password?
        user_obj.admin = is_admin
        user_obj.staff = is_staff
        user_obj.save(using=self._db)
        return user_obj

    def create_superuser(self, email, first_name, last_name, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            first_name,
            last_name,
            password=password,
            is_staff=True,
            is_admin=True
        )
        return user

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    # active = models.BooleanField(default=True) #can login
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False) #staff not superuser
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False) #superuser

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_first_name(self):
        return self.email

    def get_last_name(self):
        return self.email


    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.staff

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.admin
```

formy.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import (
    authenticate,
    get_user_model,
    login,
    logout,
    )
from django.contrib.auth.forms import ReadOnlyPasswordHashField
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group


User = get_user_model()

class UserAdminCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for creating new users. Includes all the required
    fields, plus a repeated password."""
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name')

    def clean_password2(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super(UserAdminCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

views.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from barbers.forms import BarberProfileForm
from barbers.models import BarberProfile
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from django.contrib.auth import (
    authenticate,
    get_user_model,
    login,
    logout,
    )
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render, get_object_or_404
from .forms import BarberRegisterForm, UserLoginForm, UserRegisterForm, UserAdminCreationForm

def register_view(request):

    print(request.user.is_authenticated())

    register_title = "Register"
    register_form = UserAdminCreationForm(request.POST or None)
    if register_form.is_valid():
        user = register_form.save(commit=False)
        password = register_form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        user.groups.add(Group.objects.get(name='customers'))
        new_user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=password)
        login(request, new_user)
        if next:
            return redirect(next)
        return redirect("/my-barbers/{0}".format(request.user.id), user=request.user)

    context = {
        "register_form": register_form,
        "register_title": register_title,
    }

    return render (request, "login.html", context)
```

Comment: Can you share your `models.py` with the customer `User` model? Also, your `settings.py`?

Comment: @JensAstrup I have now included my models.py, forms.py and views.py. I think the code is quite dirty but any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's your custom job user model?

Maybe you inherit `AbstractUser` or `AbstractBaseUser`.

But when you need to use `groups`, ou have to inherit `PermissionsMixin`

```
    from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionMixin
```

you can check in [django github code here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py)

here's part of the code

```
class PermissionsMixin(models.Model):
    """
    Add the fields and methods necessary to support the Group and Permission
    models using the ModelBackend.
    """
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(
        _('superuser status'),
        default=False,
        help_text=_(
            'Designates that this user has all permissions without '
            'explicitly assigning them.'
        ),
    )
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(
        Group,
        verbose_name=_('groups'),
        blank=True,
        help_text=_(
            'The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions '
            'granted to each of their groups.'
        ),
        related_name="user_set",
        related_query_name="user",
    )
```

Hope solving well!

### Adding

This is my part of user model. You should inherit both `BaseUser` and `PermissionsMixin`. Then you can use `groups` from `PermissionsMixin`.

```
class JobUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, TimeStampedModel):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name="Email",
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
        db_index=True,
    )
    user_type = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        verbose_name="User type",
        # 0 - staff
        # 1 - employer
        # 2 - employee
        choices=CHOICES.USER_CHOICES,
        default=2,
    )
    ...
```

> So your User model will be like...

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    # active = models.BooleanField(default=True) #can login
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False) #staff not superuser
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False) #superuser
    ...
```

Also don't forget import `PermissionMixin` in top of your code.

Hope solving well!

Comment: I inherit from 'Abstract Base User' as you can see in my models.py (which I have just added to my question). Not quite sure what you mean about PermissionsMixin. Would appreciate if you could have one last look at my code to see where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Oh sorry for late check. You should inherit 'PermissionsMixin' either.

Comment: I add my user model to answer. You can check it. Just ignore `TimeStampedModel` (it's my own base model with creatd_at)